# What was it that Emilia Clarke (Daenerys) was really eating in "A Golden Crown" (S01E06 )

Tags: game-of-thrones, props

I could not find much on this, but we see Daenerys Targaryen eat a horses heart.

What I want to know what was it really, what was the prop made out out of?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It was made of a gummy bear-like material:

Around 1:50

[GoT wiki](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Stallion_heart):

> According to actress Emilia Clarke (Daenerys), the prop she used for
>   the stallion's heart was made of gummy bear-like material, which
>   actually tasted awful, so the difficulty with which she seems to be
>   choking it down is actually a genuine physical reaction. It had to be
>   something she could really bite, chew, and swallow, because it would
>   have seemed fake if she was only miming the act of eating a prop
>   without actually consuming pieces of it.

Comment: All that money and they couldn't spring for some cherry flavoring? Giant gummy bears are delicious!

Comment: @GGMG That would make the acting bit hard

Comment: @Alexander that doesn't matter it would still be a fun part

Comment: @ChristopherPeart No, I believe it matters. She has to show eating the heart of a horse it not like biting into a cherry flavored gummy bear. The reflex of the gag makes it look more natural.